# What is the difference between log4j and java.util.logging

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging

Which is best for getting the log files of user logged in his account? Explain with a small example... Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log4j is a defacto standard logging library for Java.

Java.util.logging is a built in logging mechanism in Java, but that doesn't make it the greatest...

Use Log4j and its [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html). This way, you can easily log different user accounts like this:

```
MDC.put(user);
logger.log("Deleted something important!");
```

This way, if logging is configured correctly, in your log output you will see something like this:

> [user Alice] Deleted something important!

and this will work for every user in a multi user environment.

Note: if you're starting a new project, I'd suggest using [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/index.html) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). This combination is even more powerful than log4j or java.util.logging.

I have been using this combination for some time and it has really paid off handsomely. Very useful for bug squashing and auditing user interaction, among other things.

Comment: @darioo..can u plz suggest good tutorials how to use slf4j and Logback

Comment: @dude: read the [Logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html). Everything you need, you will find there.

Comment: I would rather think that java.util.logging is the standard as it comes pre-installed. For example java.util.logging is available on Android - try Log4J there.

Comment: Thanks for bringing attention ton MDC (and NDC). Great stuff.